# How to use filter and save value in state in React?

Tags: reactjs

how to use filter in React such that from `data` only selected true object should be filtered out and from that filtered object only `value` should be saved in state.

How it can be done in Reactjs .

I just want to  save `four` in `state` because its has only `selected` `true`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const data = [
  {
    key: 1,
    value: "four",
    selected: true
  },
  {
    key: 2,
    value: "fours",
    selected: false
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState();

  console.log(state);

  data.forEach((item) => {
    setState(data.filter((person) => person.selected === true));
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: `const [state, setState] = useState(data.filter(person => person.selected));` and remove `data.forEach...setState` from render method, otherwise you will get infinite rendering

Comment: i tried this also but it gives me complete object where as i want the ```value``` only

Comment: you need to additionally use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const filteredData = data.filter((person) => person.selected ).map((person) => person.value)
setState(filteredData);
```

Comment: i tried this also but it gives me complete object where as i want the value only

Comment: try using "map"

Answer (score 0):

You can directly set in useState like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const data = [
  {
    key: 1,
    value: "four",
    selected: true
  },
  {
    key: 2,
    value: "fours",
    selected: false
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(data.filter((person) => person.selected === true));

  console.log(state);



  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>{state[0].value}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If your data change frequently you can create another variable and set :

```
const getFilterData = data.filter((person) => person.selected )
setState(getFilterData);
```

Live demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-raman-s8qhb

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the `useEffect` hook to initialize the state with filtered data when component is mounted.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const data = [
    {
        key: 1,
        value: "four",
        selected: true
    },
    {
        key: 2,
        value: "fours",
        selected: false
    }
];

export default function App() {
    const [state, setState] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const selectedItems = data.filter(d => d.value);
        setState(selectedItems);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
            <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
        </div>
    );
}
```